# Use pytest to check that an application file imports a module?

Tags: python, pytest, python-import

This fails:

```
def test_main_imports_pathlib():
    print(f'"pathlib" in sys.modules {"pathlib" in sys.modules}') # prints "True"
    if 'pathlib' in sys.modules:
        del sys.modules['pathlib']
    import core.__main__ 
    assert 'pathlib' in sys.modules
```

but `__main__.py` looks like this:

```
import pathlib
```

NB things are set up with conventional "src" and "tests" top directories and, yes, `__main__.py` definitely gets imported in the above test.

Is there a way to test whether an application file imports a module using pytest? I'm open to the idea that this might be dismissed an an "implementation detail" and that I should be testing for something bigger. But in fact I think that this is a trivial example of something you might well be justified in checking: what imports what...

In fact I'd like to understand *why* the above fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is most probably that `core.__main__` is already loaded, and importing it won't load it again. You have to also remove that module from the module cache, e.g. something like:

```py
def test_main_imports_pathlib():
    if 'pathlib' in sys.modules:
        del sys.modules['pathlib']
    if '__main__' in sys.modules:
        del sys.modules['__main__']
    import core.__main__ 
    assert 'pathlib' in sys.modules
```

Another possibility would be to force a reload of the imported module instead:

```py
from importlib import reload

def test_main_imports_pathlib():
    if 'pathlib' in sys.modules:
        del sys.modules['pathlib']
    main_loaded = 'core.__main__' in sys.modules
    import core.__main__ 
    if main_loaded:
        reload(core.__main__)
    assert 'pathlib' in sys.modules
```

As mentioned in the comment, this second version does not rely on the correct name of your module in the module cache, and is therefore more reliable.

*Update*: Prevent double loading as proposed by mike rodent.

Comment: Thanks very much. For some reason the first solution didn't work (after I found the other culprit test which was importing `__main__`). For the record, I also tried `if ... del sys.modules['core']` and even `if ... del sys.modules['core.__main__']`.  But the second solution is perfect.

Comment: Yes, the second solution does not rely on getting the right module name used in the module cache, I realized this after I wrote the first one. Added a note to the answer...

Comment: There's a slight improvement to your answer which I suggest. The problem is that if `core.__main__` has NOT been loaded, your second solution causes the load to happen twice. I examined the contents of `sys.modules` and in fact there *is* an entry `'core.__main__'` after `import`... so I suggest testing for that: if absent use `import`, but if present use `reload`. There is ANOTHER complication after that though! You have to make sure the `import` line precedes the `reload` line (in Eclipse at least): otherwise the IDE complains that `core` hasn't been imported!